# Xna 4.0 3D Cameras & Models, rotation does not work right

Tags: 3d, xna, camera, rotation

Hi I am getting a headache with cameras and models rotation. the camera seems to be working but the rotation on the model just seems to be messed up. What i want is the model to turn a little bit in the spot it is but it seems to be turning and moving it around a circle. Here is my code.
My float angle keeps increasing by 0.05f when i press right

Draw Function:

```
        Vector3 cameraRotate = Vector3.Transform(offSetVector, Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle));
        Vector3 cameraLookat = cameraPos + cameraRotate;
        Matrix viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPos ,  cameraLookat, Vector3.Up);
        float aspect = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio;
        Matrix projectionMatrix = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4, aspect, 0.1f, 200.0f);
        carTypeOneMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(pos) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle);        
        baseModel.Draw(carTypeOneMatrix , viewMatrix, projectionMatrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about 3D on XNA, but as far as I know, the CreateRotationX, CreateRotationY and CreateRotationZ creates rotation based on the world global axis...

I did a little search and I think [this maybe will help you](http://stevehazen.wordpress.com/2010/02/15/matrix-basics-how-to-step-away-from-storing-an-orientation-as-3-angles/)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, this line:

```
carTypeOneMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(pos) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle);
```

should be:

```
carTypeOneMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(pos);
```

Whenever you create a combination of matrices to transform the model to world space in Xna, remember "SRT" which means Scale, Rotate, Translate. It is the order you combine the matrices. You had the translate one first, then the rotate one. My suggestion has the rotate first, then the translate.